# What is the fastest way to populate an array of jQuery objects with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large array of in memory jquery elements which I need to populate with HTML.  Just to be clear these elements are not in the DOM but are stored like so:

```
var els = [$('<div>'), $('<div>'), $('<div>')]; etc..etc...
```

These elements are continuously appended and removed to the DOM as a user scrolls (think infinite scroll);  And also these elements need to be manipulated whether they are in the DOM or not.  Hence the reason for storing them in an array.

On load I need to populate these empty jQuery objects with html and to make matters more tricky each fragment requires a Canvas element.  By scrapping jQuery and using raw javascript for these operations I have significantly improved the time it takes to complete on large arrays.  This is my current method:

```
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')

//draw stuff on in memory canvas here

    var html = '<div>'
                 +'<div>'
                   +'<button>'
                     /*imagine more elements here*/ 
                   +'</button>'
                 +'</div>'
               '</div>';

    els[index][0].innerHTML = html;
    els[index][0].firstChlid().firstChild().appendChild(canvas);
```

What I would like to know is if this is the fastest possible way of pushing HTML in an already created array of empty jquery objects. If not what would you suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it have to be all loaded right away before you do anything or can you lazy load it?

Comment: documentFragments and native JS with cloning of elements is the fastest, and not arrays with a bunch of jQuery objects.

Comment: Sadly yes... it needs to be loaded from the beginning.  It is actually infinately more complex than a simple infinite scroll, but for the sake of simplicity in this question that is how I have described it.

Comment: @adeneo I fully understand that.  But this is not about getting html into the DOM quickly,  this is about populating jQuery objects.  For entirely different reasons.

Comment: Yes, and working with fragments and native nodeLists will be much faster than arrays and jQuery objects.

Comment: You could use wrapAll within a looping method like map or each for your array items

Comment: @adeneo  I'm certain that is the case, but there are some very good reasons why we need an array of jQuery objects. Without a total redesign and rewriting a huge amount of jQuery in raw javascript it is not really an option. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @blachawk Thanks... it's certainly a possibility but i don't believe it would be any faster than the method above.  I actually expect it would be slower would it not?